# Is there a way to save open Xcode tabs?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to save the current 'workspace' in Xcode and/or create keyboard shortcuts for different workspaces? Not the workspace as xcode defines it (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html), but rather the open files and split panels etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can "Create Snapshot" from the File menu. Give the snapshot a name. The next time you open XCode it should be in the state you left it.

Actually, scratch that. I just tested and it's not even necessary. If I open multiple tabs and then close Xcode, when I reopen Xcode the tabs are still there. Is that what you mean?